# TextView.setText() only displays final change after sleep()

Tags: java, android, xml

I am relatively new to Android and the finer details often result in my programme not running how I want it to. 
The `TextView` (in this case tvQuestion) is supposed to change its contents, wait, and then change them again, however the first change is not seen, and the programme waits and displays only the last change. 
Side note, all the contents are gathered from a SQLite Database and put into a custom object Question.
I believe the problem is in the `onClick(View v)` method, however any and all help is appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
package com.infernalpoison.falseorfact.util;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.infernalpoison.falseorfact.R;

public class Play extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
 final private Context playContext = this;
 private int correct = 0;
 private int wrong = 0;
 private TextView tvQuestion;
 private ImageView btnFalse, btnFact;
 private Question questionObj;
 private Thread thrNewQuestion = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        DatabaseConstruction dbc = new DatabaseConstruction(playContext);
        try {
            dbc.open();
            questionObj = dbc.getRdmQ();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            tvQuestion.setText(questionObj.getQuestion());
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);// Remove title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); // Remove notification bar

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);

    tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvQuestion);
    btnFact = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_fact);
    btnFact.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFalse = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_false);
    btnFalse.setOnClickListener(this);

    questionObj = new Question();

    thrNewQuestion.run();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        **case R.id.btn_fact:
            factSelect();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            thrNewQuestion.run();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_false:
            falseSelect();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            thrNewQuestion.run();
            break;**
    }
}

private void factSelect() {
    if (questionObj.isAnswer() == true) {
        correct++;
        tvQuestion.setText("That is Correct! Well Done!");
    } else {
        wrong++;
        tvQuestion.setText("That is Incorrect. " + questionObj.getFactCorrection());
        //TODO ADD MECH TO EXIT
    }
}

private void falseSelect() {
    if (questionObj.isAnswer() == false) {
        correct++;
        tvQuestion.setText("That is Correct! Well Done!");
    } else {
        wrong++;
        tvQuestion.setText("That is Incorrect. " + questionObj.getFalseCorrection());
        //TODO ADD MECH TO EXIT
    }
}
}
```

And the xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.infernalpoison.falseorfact.util.PlayFragment">

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/btn_false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvQuestion"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Empty" />

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/btn_fact"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_fact" />
```

Thanks in advance.
PS this is my first post so please notify me if you need more info!

Comment: Using of raw `Thread`s is discouraged in android. Use `AsyncTask` instead. [Example](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: take a look at threading. it looks like you let the UiThread sleep, but that also causes the changing of the textview to freeze

Comment: You are directly calling "thrNewQuestion.run();" aka Thread.run(), which simply executes your run-method on the UIThread (as @R.Adang) already mentioned. You should call "thrNewQuestions.start();" to start the new thread, which will then execute the run method.

Comment: @Heyyou True. I meant for short background tasks that are expected to have a callback on the UI thread, like what OP is targeting.

Comment: @Heyyou the `ThrNewQuestion` Thread was created because every time the programme used that code it would skip about 122 frames. `Thread.sleep()` was used because I had no idea what a `Handler` does and was unsure of `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of:

```
  try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        thrNewQuestion.run();
```

Do something like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            thrNewQuestion.run();
        }
    }, 2000);
```